# после камеры не выполняются команды gsm модуля

Tags: arduino

```
#include <SPI.h>

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>



// This is a snapshot sketch using the VC0706 library.
// On start, the Arduino will find the camera and GSM sheild and
// then snap a photo, saving it GPRS on FTP server 
// Public domain.
#include <Adafruit_VC0706.h>

// On Uno: camera TX connected to pin 2, camera RX to pin 3:

SoftwareSerial cameraconnection = SoftwareSerial(3,2);
Adafruit_VC0706 cam = Adafruit_VC0706(&cameraconnection);
SoftwareSerial Gsmcon = SoftwareSerial(6,5);


char bufgsm[512];
 int i = 0 ; 
//===========================================================================================
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
 Gsmcon.begin(9600);
 lat:  Gsmcon.println("AT");delay(1000);Read_Ans();
      if (bufgsm[6] != 'O') goto lat;

       Gsmcon.println("AT+SAPBR=0,1");delay(5000);Read_Ans();

lcon: Gsmcon.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");delay(1000);Read_Ans();
   //   if (bufgsm[33] != 'O') goto lcon;

lapn: Gsmcon.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"internet.mts.ru\"");delay(1000);Read_Ans(); 
   //   if (bufgsm[44] != 'O') goto lapn;

lSAPB:       Gsmcon.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1"); delay(10000);Read_Ans();
    // if (bufgsm[16] != 'O') goto lSAPB;

lftpcid: Gsmcon.println("AT+FTPCID=1");delay(10000);Read_Ans(); 
  //     if (bufgsm[15] != 'O') goto lftpcid;

lftpserv: Gsmcon.println("AT+FTPSERV=\"c93080hf.beget.tech\""); delay(1000);Read_Ans();
  //     if (bufgsm[38] != 'O') goto lftpserv;

luser: Gsmcon.println("AT+FTPUN=\"c93080hf_vovalutohin\""); delay(1000);Read_Ans();
  //     if (bufgsm[20] != 'O') goto luser;

lfppw: Gsmcon.println("AT+FTPPW=\"Pli_Kmh\""); delay(1000);Read_Ans();
    //   if (bufgsm[24] != 'O') goto lfppw;

lfputp: Gsmcon.println("AT+FTPPUTPATH=\"/Gsm/\""); delay(1000); Read_Ans(); 
      //  if (bufgsm[37] != 'O') goto lfputp;

lfputn: Gsmcon.println("AT+FTPPUTNAME=\"Camera42.jpg\""); delay(1000);Read_Ans();
     //   if (bufgsm[37] != 'O') goto lfputn;

     Gsmcon.println("AT+FTPMODE=0"); delay(1000);Read_Ans();

     Gsmcon.println("AT+FTPTYPE=\"I\""); delay(1000);Read_Ans();

  Gsmcon.println("AT+FTPPUTOPT=\"APPE\""); delay(1000);Read_Ans();
  Gsmcon.println("AT+FTPPUT=1");delay(10000);Read_Ans();delay(10000);
  if (cam.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Camera Found:");
    cam.setImageSize(VC0706_640x480); 
  } else {
    Serial.println("No camera found");
    return;
  }


  }
//============================================================================
void loop() {
   if (! cam.takePicture()) 
   { Serial.println("Failed to snap!");}
  else 
    {Serial.println("Picture taken!");}

  // Create an image with the name IMAGExx.JPG
char filename[13];
strcpy(filename, "IMAGE00.JPG");
 for  (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    filename[5] = '0' + i/10;
    filename[6] = '0' + i%10;
   }        


  // Get the size of the image (frame) taken  
  uint16_t jpglen = cam.frameLength();
  Serial.print("Storing ");
  Serial.print(jpglen, DEC);
  Serial.print(" byte image.");



  int32_t time = millis();
  //pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  // Read all the data up to # bytes!
  byte wCount = 0; // For counting # of writes
  while (jpglen > 0) {
    // read 32 bytes at a time;
    uint8_t *buffer;
    uint8_t bytesToRead = min(32, jpglen); // change 32 to 64 for a speedup but may not work with all setups!
    buffer = cam.readPicture(bytesToRead);

  //  imgFile.write(buffer, bytesToRead);
    if(++wCount >= 64) { // Every 2K, give a little feedback so it doesn't appear locked up
      Serial.print('.');
      wCount = 0;
    }
    Serial.print("Read ");  Serial.print(bytesToRead, DEC); Serial.println(" bytes");
    jpglen -= bytesToRead;
   Gsmcon.println("AT+FTPPUT=2,32"); 
        delay(5000);
        Read_Ans(); 
      // if (bufgsm[37] != 'O') goto lfput;

        Gsmcon.write(buffer, bytesToRead); 
        delay(5000);
       Read_Ans(); 
  }

        Gsmcon.println("AT+FTPPUT=2,0"); 
        delay(5000);
        Read_Ans(); 
//  imgFile.close();

  time = millis() - time;
  Serial.println("done!");
  Serial.print(time); Serial.println(" ms elapsed");
   Serial.println("Snap in 30 secs...");
 delay(30000);
           // biggest
//  Gsm.begin(9600);
}
void Read_Ans() {
    i = 0 ;  
wh: while (Gsmcon.available() > 0) {
    char inByte = Gsmcon.read();
    Serial.write(inByte);
    bufgsm[i] = inByte;
    i+=1;
  }
  Serial.print("Длина ответа ");
  Serial.println(i ,DEC); 
// if (i==0) {
  // delay(5000);
   //goto wh;
 //}
 }
```

Comment: Для камеры хватает скорости 9600?)